# Write a custom JSON interpreter for a file that looks like json but isnt using Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, paradox-scripting

What I need to do is to write a module that can read and write files that use the PDX script language. This language looks alot like json but has enough differences that a custom encoder/decoder is needed to do anything with those files (without a mess of regex substitutions which would make maintenance hell). I originally went with just reading them as txt files, and use regex to find and replace things to convert it to valid json. This lead me to my current point, where any additions to the code requires me to write far more code than I would want to, just to support some small new thing. So using a custom json thing I could write code that shows what valid key:value pairs are, then use that to handle the files. To me that will be alot less code and alot easier to maintain.

So what does this code look like? In general it looks like this (tried to put all possible syntax, this is not an example of a working file):

```
@key = value # this is the definition for the scripted variable

key = {
    # This is a comment. No multiline comments
    function # This is a single key, usually optimize_memory

    # These are the accepted key:value pairs. The quoted version is being phased out
    key = "value"
    key = value
    key = @key # This key is using a scripted variable, defined either in the file its in or in the `scripted_variables` folder. (see above for example on how these are initially defined)
    # type is what the key type is. Like trigger:planet_stability where planet_stability is a trigger
    key = type:key

    # Variables like this allow for custom names to be set. Mostly used for flags and such things
    [[VARIABLE_NAME]
        math_key = $VARIABLE_NAME$
    ]

    # this is inline math, I dont actually understand how this works in the script language yet as its new. The "<" can be replaced with any math symbol. 
    # Valid example: planet_stability < @[ stabilitylevel2 + 10 ]
    key < @[ key + 10 ] 
    
    # This is used alot to handle code blocks. Valid example:
    # potential = {
    #     exists = owner
    #     owner = {
    #         has_country_flag = flag_name
    #     }
    # }
    key = {
        key = value
    }

    # This is just a list. Inline brackets are used alot which annoys me...
    key = { value value }
}
```

The major differences between json and PDX script is the nearly complete lack of quotations, using an equals sign instead of a colon for separation and no comma's at the end of the lines. Now before you ask me to change the PDX code, I cant. Its not mine. This is what I have to work with and cant make any changes to the syntax. And no I dont want to convert back and forth as I have already mentioned this would require alot of work. I have attempted to look for examples of this, however all I can find are references to convert already valid json to a python object, which is not what I want. So I cant give any examples of what I have already done, as I cant find anywhere to even start.

Some additional info:

- Order of key:value pairs does not technically matter, however it is expected to be in a certain order, and when not in that order causes issues with mods and conflict solvers
- bool properties always use `yes` or `no` rather than `true` or `false`
- Lowercase is expected and in some cases required
- Math operators are used as separators as well, eg `>=`, `<=` ect
- The list of syntax is not exhaustive, but should contain most of the syntax used in the language

Past work:

My last attempts at this all revolved around converting it from a text file to a json file. This was alot of work just to get a small piece of this to work.

Example:

```
        potential = {
            exists = owner
            owner = {
                is_regular_empire = yes
                is_fallen_empire = no
            }
            NOR = {
                has_modifier = resort_colony
                has_modifier = slave_colony
                uses_habitat_capitals = yes
            }
        }
```

And what i did to get most of the way to json (couldnt find a way to add quotes)

```
        test_string = test_string.replace("\n", ",")
        test_string = test_string.replace("{,", "{")
        test_string = test_string.replace("{", "{\n")
        test_string = test_string.replace(",", ",\n")
        test_string = test_string.replace("}, ", "},\n")
        test_string = "{\n" + test_string + "\n}"
        

        # Replace the equals sign with a colon
        test_string = test_string.replace(" =", ":")
```

This resulted in this:

```
{
                potential: {
                        exists: owner,
                        owner: {
                                is_regular_empire: yes,     
                                is_fallen_empire: no,       
                        },
                        NOR: {
                                has_modifier: resort_colony,
                                has_modifier: slave_colony, 
                                uses_habitat_capitals: yes, 
                        },
                }
}
```

Very very close yes, but in no way could I find a way to add the quotations to each word (I think I did try a regex sub, but wasnt able to get it to work, since this whole thing is just one unbroken string), making this attempt stuck and also showing just how much work is required just to get a very simple potential block to mostly work. However this is not the method I want anymore, one because its alot of work and two because I couldnt find anything to finish it. So a custom json interpreter is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

The classical approach (potentially leading to more code, but also more "correctness"/elegance) is probably to build a "recursive descent parser", from a bunch of conditionals/checks, loops and (sometimes recursive?) functions/handlers to deal with each of the encountered elements/characters on the input stream. An implicit parse/call tree might be sufficient if you directly output/print the JSON equivalent, or otherwise you could also create a representation/model in memory for later output/conversion.

Related book recommendation could be "Language Implementation Patterns" by Terence Parr, me avoiding to promote my own interpreters and introductory materials :-) In case you need further help, maybe write me?

Comment: Im trying to avoid excessive code as that will simply limit what I want to do. What I want is something that can read this code, but not because it knows what it all does. Rather it does that this code is valid. This way I can implement a module for PDX script that can read/write anything without ever really needing to update it, other than when they add new code like the inline scripts, or the new language update (that isnt for the game I am currently using)